# Error when updating values in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I try to update the score of a player in the leaderboard. I get the error that players/update is not found.

```
PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer,{score: 5})
```

Error:

> error-update failed: Method '/players/update' not found

Comment: It would be much clearer, if you'd share more code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your collection on the client or server side only? Try to define it outside ./client or ./server folder, e.g. in  lib/